# Java : how can i remove array of words from a LinkedList<ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, linked-list

i have tried this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] common = {"hello", "there", "hi"};
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    LinkedList<ArrayList<String>> las = new LinkedList<>();
    list.add("how");
    list.add("there");
    las.add(list);
    for (int i = 0; i < las.size(); i++) {
        String[] tStringArray = null;
        Object[] tObject = las.get(i).toArray();
        String[] tString = Arrays.copyOf(tObject, tObject.length, String[].class);
        for (int j = 0; j < tString.length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < common.length; k++) {
                if (tString[j] == common[k]) {
                    tStringArray = (String[]) ArrayUtils.removeElement(tString, common[k]);
                }
            }
        }
        ArrayList<String> tList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(tStringArray));
        las.set(i, tList);
    }
}
```

---

i have used commons lang library.
i have String array of commons {"hello", "there", "hi"}
and i have Linked list in form of LinkedList(ArrayList(String))
and i added some element to Linked List and now i want to remove all words from commons from Linked List. How can i do that? please help..

Comment: `if (tString[j] == common[k]) {` you need to use `equals` for String comparation

Comment: It still gives an error in second last line converting array to List

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove all common words you can use `List.removeAll` method:

```
list.removeAll(Arrays.asList(common));
```